# VS2013 VB - Trying to add a Powershell output to ListBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, powershell, listbox, powershell-cmdlet

I am having some real trouble here. Working in Visual Studio 2013 Express, in Visual Basic. I have a form which has a ListBox. And a function which calls a PowerShell cmd-let 'Get-Process'. I am trying to get this output to display in said Listbox.

The code I have so far is below:

```
Private Function RunScript(ByVal scriptText As String) As String
        ' create Powershell runspace 
        Dim MyRunSpace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()
        MyRunSpace.Open()
        ' create a pipeline and feed it the script text 
        Dim MyPipeline As Pipeline = MyRunSpace.CreatePipeline()

        MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText)
        MyPipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String")

        ' execute the script 
        Dim PSOut As Collection(Of PSObject) = MyPipeline.Invoke()

        ' close the runspace 
        MyRunSpace.Close()

        For Each Id In PSOut
            CheckList1.BeginUpdate()
            CheckList1.Items.Add(Id)
            CheckList1.EndUpdate()
        Next

    End Function
```

All this does is display the first line of the PowerShell output and nothing else. What am I missing? I thought maybe it needs to be told to loop through the collection, but I cant find anything like that in my searches thus far...

Any help will be appreciated.

Phill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
MyPipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String")
```

Just remove it.

It's causing your output to be formatted as a string. Meaning after that you need to parse it back to a list of string, and then potentially do even more parsing. You don't need all that, because it's much easier to work with a list of PSObject, when each of them is actually a PSObject, and not a string wrapper.

Also regarding process format, you may consider using this instead of just `Id`:

```
Id.Properties("Name").Value.ToString()
```

This will populate your checklist control with a list of process names. Also consider changing your variable name, i.e. `Id` to `psProcess`, to reflect what it really is.

Comment: Wow - ok this is nearly perfect. Is there any way I can add another column to this output? Say, the current Id of process as well as the above? Or the CPU usage? Just other the other columns of the Get-Process output...?

Comment: @phillcouzens: Yes, just add other properties of Get-Process, as you find useful. You can get a list of valid properties using `Get-Process | gm` in Powershell. You can even make it part of the query, i.e. `Get-Process | select id,name`, then enumerate through all properties and output them in order, for every entry in results.

Comment: Ahh, apologies - I meant add the other columns from the PowerShell output, like the name or ID to the listbox? Or does the listbox control not support this?

Comment: @IMPhill: You mean to display those properties as columns? You would probably need either ListView or a DataGridView. Read about the difference here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a030e65d-621a-4b7c-8eff-15811e828440/difference-between-datagridview-and-listview-control?forum=winforms. You can always use a custom/3rd-party control, such as [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at this. It's seems DataGrid view is probably what I'm after. Multi-colmn, many rows. Thanks again for this.